# Will a video played after a user gesture and iframe refresh be blocked by a browser's autoplay policy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, safari, cross-browser

Many browsers have policies that block autoplaying videos. See for example: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Let's say there is a workflow similar to the following (I know it seems contrived, but it's the best option at this point, I can go into detail why if anyone is curious):

1. User clicks on an iframe video to play it.
2. The iframe sets a cookie to set it to play after an iframe refresh (window.location.reload())
3. On reload, the player reads the cookie, and plays the video.

Would any browsers see this as an autoplay and potentially block the video from playing? Or would they recognize the iframe as having been interacted with, and not block this playback?

I'm mostly curious about Safari, though other browsers like Firefox and Chrome would be of interest as well.

Thank you!

Comment: A new page load requires the user to re-auth the autoplay, even when it's an iframe.